# How to Calculate frequencies, $C$ and Group $Cg$ from a dispersion relation?

Tags: waves, velocity, dispersion

Some people requested what was the context of the question and this is where it comes from:

> "Given the dispersion relation: $w^2=w_0^2+A^2k^2$ ( $w_0$ and $A$ are constants)
>
> 1. Which frequencies can propagate in the medium provided by the relation (each frequency needs to have a linear λ)
> 2. Calculate C and Cg (group velocity) and draw them as a function of w (qualitatively)"

The problem i have is that i understand linear λ as λ not being to the power of something.
But none of the end results i have reached to try to find 1)'s solution doesn't have a linear λ (if we consider linear λ what i have explained above)

Comment: *I need to provide all frequencies* What does that mean?

Comment: all the frequencies that can propagate in this medium (the one which satisfies the given equation ). Basically isolating f as a function of the other variables, but the thing is that the λ (wavelength) has to be linear

Comment: what do you mean "the wavelength has to be linear"? Perhaps you should give th the *exact wording* of    the original  question. Maybe  they  meant that the amplitude is small enough that you can use the linear wave equation?

Comment: The question is translated from Catalan (language): "Given the dispersion relation: $w^2 = w_0^2 + A^2 k^2$ ( $w_0$ and A are constants) 1) Which frequencies can propagate in the medium provided by the relation (each frequency needs to have a linear λ) 2) Calculate C and Cg (group velocity) and draw them as a function of w (qualitatively)"

Answer (score 0):

1. The first question isn't perfectly clear, but I think they are asking you to solve the equation for $k$ (not $k^2$).  Real $k$ is required for a wavelike solution, which requires $\omega^2>\omega_0^2$.
2. $\omega = \sqrt{\omega_0^2+Ak^2}$, so the phase speed $C=\omega/k=\sqrt{\frac{\omega_0^2}{k}+A^2k}$ and the group velocity $C_g$ is  $\frac{d\omega}{dk}=\frac{k}{\sqrt{\omega_0^2+Ak^2}}$